# Meteor 1.0.2.1 session variable not staying set

Tags: javascript, meteor

In the following code i'm expecting `{{#if adding_answers}}` Session Variable to be `true` when I click the button. It fires the `"click .setup_answers':function"` but the template `{{> newAnswers}}` never displays because `{{#if adding_answers}}` it is not true. I see it get set to true via console.log but hen it returns to the HTML nothing.
I thought that by setting it to a value that meteor reactive would cause it to be seen?

HTML Code

```
<template name="newQuestions">
    {{#if adding_answers}} <!-- Session Variable -->
        {{> newAnswers}}
    {{/if}}

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Questions</h3>
                <p></p>
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="inputQuestion">Question</label>
                        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="inputQuestion"     id="inputQuestion" autofocus="1" placeholder="Enter New Question" rows="5">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="setup_answers btn-primary">Setup Answers</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>`
```

JS Code

```
`Template.newQuestions.events({
  "click .archive": function(event, template){
    return Meteor.call('archiveTodo',this._id,!this.archived);
  },
  'click .todochecked':function(event,template){
    return Meteor.call('completeTodo',this._id,!this.completed);
  },
  'click .setup_answers':function(event,template){
    var question = $('#inputQuestion').val(); // Question must be entered.
    if (question === "") {
      alert("The question can not be blank.");
      Session.set('adding_answers',false); 
    } else {
      Session.set('adding_answers',true); // Causes template newAnswers to be displayed
    }
    return session.get('adding_answers');
  }
});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot return anything from event handler like Session variables

and second you need to define helper for `adding_answers` shown as follows for code to wok

```
Template.newQuestions.helpers({
   adding_answers: function(){
    return Session.get('adding_answers')
  }
})
```

Read more on helpers [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)

Comment: @pld32 ok, that looks like big project, can you point out where it is not being used ?

Comment: @pld32 i see it being used, Check out `client\views` and then any js file inside `js` directory

Comment: OMG- Now things are looking good. Can you clarify session variables for me some. I see that i'm getting "session is not defined" in console. Does a session variable have to be defined with a default first or something?

Comment: Sure, If you not defining session variable and trying access same by `Session.get('variableName')` then you will get `undefined` as value. You can set its default value `Session.setDefaullt`

Comment: and you are getting "session not defined" you are getting due to you are using 'session' with **s in small case**. `Session` is with **S in capital**